# Find the matrices which commute with another

Tags: matrices

I'm studying matrices and do not find the way to solve this exercize :

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ Find the matrices B which look like $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & b \end{bmatrix}$ with $b \in \ \mathbb{C}$ which commute with A.

I've tried for b=1, b=2... but they do not commute how is it possible to determine the B-matrices such as they commute with A ?

Thanks

Comment: Commuting matrices means $AB - BA = 0$. Why not multiply the two matrices above as $AB$ and $BA$, subtract and find those values of $b$ which satisfy the equation?

Comment: Check again for $b=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$, $$B=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & b \end{bmatrix}$$ . Thus $$AB=BA$$ gives$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & b \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & b \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \implies\begin{bmatrix}2 &0 &b\\0 &1& 0\\2&0&b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&2\\0&1&0\\b&0&b\end{bmatrix}$ which gives $b=2$

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate that
$$
  A B = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & b \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 2&0&b \end{pmatrix} \\
  B A = \begin{pmatrix} 2&0&2\\0&1&0\\b&0&b\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then, by inspection youi can see those are equal only if $b=2$, which is the answer.

Comment: maybe the second row is wrong

Comment: corrected. Now.